# Visual 2015 + Qt 5.6: Program execution very slow in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, debugging

I noticed that program execution in Visual debug mode is very slow (both release and debug version of the program). The performance drop impacts also non-Qt code which is just called in the GUI. In comparison to an old version based on MFC, the same non-Qt code runs > 10 times slower. I know that I can just start the program without debugger and everything is fine. However, the debugger is practical for reason. Does someone have a tip what causes the debugger problems?

Comment: In Tools->Options, Debugging->General, uncheck "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging"

Comment: @dgrat, please also disable the symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols, please also disable the IntelliTrace under TOOLS->Options->IntelliTrace .

Comment: Let me get this straight.  You have an old version of a program using MFC, and a new version of the same program but using QT, but the new program is slower in the non-gui parts?   Are you 100% certain?  Have you measured the same non-gui parts properly (with code timers, etc)?

Comment: No I was not measuring time "properly".  I just estimated the total time the program requires for finishing a function.

Comment: @dgrat, one suggestion is that you could use some performance tool like the VS profiler to really collect the time of every functions in your VS, and know that which function really impacts the performance.

Comment: The diagnostic tools entirly slow the debugging down. The question is just why this happens with Qt but not MFC?